# Log emails sent by devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise for user authentication in rails. How can I log the emails sent by devise. I have a model for storing the emails. How can I hook in so that before devise sends emails for new registration, change password, forgot password etc, I can just store the emails in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `config/initializers/devise_mail_logger.rb` and re-open the Devise::Mailer class

**devise_mail_logger.rb:**

```
Devise::Mailer.class_eval do

  def devise_mail_with_logger(record, action)
    email = devise_mail_without_logger(record, action)
    #code to log this email to DB goes here
  end

  alias_method_chain :devise_mail, :logger
end
```

The `email` object will have the message body, subject, recipient details. You can pass this object to the model you have to store emails.